# how to create exe file in vb to be distributed to other

Tags: vb6

I have created exe file of VB which is running properly but when I shared with other it is not running in LAN. May be I am missing someting.

Comment: How can you possibly expect any help if you don't provide more info than you have? Read up on [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You really don't want to dump programs onto network shares and expect anyone to run them from there.  Running any program not on a local fixed disk device or pseudo-disk (SSD) has risks and limitations.  Most non-trivial programs require an installation process as well.  If this wasn't true then "portable applications" wouldn't even be a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what you are doing I suspect your problem is with File I/O.

If you are using SQL, MySQL, Access or some other database the simplest thing to do is use ODBC to name the file on your LAN.  There are other solutions.

If you are using "flat" (text) files and you are pointing at files on your drive C that is where your network will look for them.  A simple solution to this is to map an unused drive letter to the file.  Then access that file in your vb program using the pseudo drive.

Charlie

Comment: "Flat" file ≠ text file.

Comment: you are right (of course) flat files can be CSV files, BAS files, FRX files etc etc etc... If the file can be accessed by NotePad (and notepad was designed to read .txt files) so one might generically call these files flat files.  I should have said (e.g. txt) in that response.  Happy Computing -Charlie